# SQL / Access - Left Join question, where do the values come from?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a cross tab query that looks like this:

```
State           Building        1          2          3          4           5

NY

SC

FL
```

The problem I am having is that I want all of the states to show up, regardless of whether or not there is data. So, I need a Left Join. Unfortunately, when I substitute the Inner Join for Left Join in the code, nothing changes. I am just trying to figure out where the problem is coming from, and I think it may be one of the following causes:

1. The query doesn't know where to pull
   the values from (The states are all
   listed in a look up  but this may
   not be where it's looking)
2. Left Joins don't work on cross tab
   queries.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's the SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Count(Demographics.ID))+0 AS CountOfID 
SELECT Demographics.State
FROM Research 
    INNER JOIN ( Demographics
        INNER JOIN [Status] 
            ON Demographics.ID=[Status].ID
            ) 
        ON (Research.ID=Demographics.ID) 
        AND (Research.ID=[Status].ID) 
WHERE ((([Status].Building_Status)='Complete'))
GROUP BY    Demographics.State,
            [Status].Building_Status 
PIVOT Research.Site In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

Ideally, I could specify the row values in the In statement above (which is currently specifying column values 1-10), but I don't think this can be done.

Comment: could you provide with sample query that you tried?

Comment: Okay, I just posted the SQL. Sorry, I still don't know how to format code on SO where it looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't completely get your example, but from your comment "I want all of the states to show up, regardless of whether or not there is data", I think you want an "OUTER" join.  Outer joins do just that -- they include data regardless of whether or not there is a "match".  Inner joins (the default) include data only if there is a match.

Hope this helps,
John

Comment: Hey John, I added some SQL above and I have actually two Inner Joins. Do I apply Outer joins to both?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much time, and it's a little tough to tell quickly without knowing your table structure.  But if you are not getting the states, try changing "INNER JOIN ( Demographics" to "LEFT OUTER JOIN (Demographics"  ... I think this will include states without matching Demographics data (the demographics data will be NULL in the result set).  It should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Also it might be useful to remove the TRANSFORM, GROUP BY, and PIVOT lines to avoid confusion while debugging this.  You can just run from SELECT to WHERE to make sure you are getting the right data, then add the other parts back in.

Comment: Jet/ACE does not distinguish between `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`. And there is no full OUTER JOIN at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should change it this way:

```
  TRANSFORM Nz(Count(Demographics.ID))+0 AS CountOfID
  SELECT Demographics.State
  FROM Demographics
      LEFT JOIN ( Research
         LEFT JOIN [Status]
              ON Demographics.ID=[Status].ID
             )
          ON (Research.ID=Demographics.ID)
          AND (Research.ID=[Status].ID)
  WHERE ((([Status].Building_Status)='Complete'))
 GROUP BY    Demographics.State,
             [Status].Building_Status
 PIVOT Research.Site In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that there may be 0 rows in table Demographics with State = 'NY' (for example) but you want to see state 'NY' in the results anyway, then you need another table e.g. States that has all the states in it, and make this your driving table:

```
SELECT States.State
FROM States
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Demographics ON Demographics.state = States.state
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a two steps solution (it is more readable)
first enclose your actual (and working) sql statment as a view

```
create view step1 as 
TRANSFORM ....
SELECT ...
FROM ...
PIVOT ...
```

and then create a select like:
(you will need a state table like @Tony Andrews says)

```
select * -- or whatever
from state 
left join step1 on state.id = step1.state
```

and that's all